# Outer constructor that has the same number of arguments as the field values

Tags: julia

How can I define an outer constructor that has same number of arguments as the field values? What I want to do is something like this:

```
struct data
    x
    y
end

function data(x, y) 
    return data(x-y, x*y)
end
```

But it obviously causes stackoverflow.

Comment: Why not use an inner constructor and `new()`?

Comment: I'v just stated julia today. According to the info on the web, new is not appropriate for long constructor. What I want actually do is writing a long constructor, though this its short in the example.

Comment: The key issue is not number of parameters but method signature. In your example the signature of both `data` methods is `data(::Any, ::Any)` and the second method overwrites the first. But you could have an outer constructor like `data(x::Number, y::Number)` and it invoke the inner constructor using `invoke` function. If it is not clear what I mean please comment and I will elaborate in the answer.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Thanks for the comment. Now, I've understood that differentiating the argument's type of constructor from those of the default constructor works. But what should I do when the default constructor already has a specific type such as float64?

Comment: If you define at least one inner constructor as @crstnbr suggested then no default constructor is automatically defined as is explained in https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/constructors/#Inner-Constructor-Methods-1. So in short - you should define an inner constructor (and not outer).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the various helpful comments, thanks to all, I changed my answer.  Here is an example in Julia 1.0.0 of what you may be after.  I am learning Julia myself, so maybe further comments can improve this example code.

```
# File test_code2.jl
struct Data
    x
    y
    Data(x, y) = new(x - y, x * y)
end

test_data = Data(105, 5)

println("Constructor example: test_data = Data(105, 5)")
println("test_data now is...: ", test_data)

#= Output
julia> include("test_code2.jl")
Constructor example: test_data = Data(105, 5)
test_data now is...: Data(100, 525)
=#
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. (maybe it is still helpful)

Comment: You return a *tuple* from your `data` function and your function is not a constructor.

Comment: @crstnbr Based on your helpful comments I used an inner constructor and new().

Comment: @hckr Based on your helpful comment I changed the code as shown.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
julia> struct datatype
         x
         y
       end

julia> function datatype_create(a,b)
         datatype(a - b, a * b)
       end
datatype_create (generic function with 1 method)

julia> methods(datatype_create)
# 1 method for generic function "datatype_create":
[1] datatype_create(a, b) in Main at none:2

julia> methods(datatype)
# 1 method for generic function "(::Type)":
[1] datatype(x, y) in Main at none:2

julia> a = datatype_create(105,5)
datatype(100, 525)

julia> b = datatype_create(1+2im,3-4im)
datatype(-2 + 6im, 11 + 2im)

julia> c = datatype_create([1 2;3 4],[4 5;6 7])
datatype([-3 -3; -3 -3], [16 19; 36 43])

julia> d = datatype_create(1.5,0.2)
datatype(1.3, 0.30000000000000004)
```

If you are absolutely Ideologically Hell Bent on using an outer constructor, then you can do something like this

```
julia> datatype(a,b,dummy) = datatype(a - b,a * b)
datatype

julia> e = datatype(105,5,"dummy")
datatype(100, 525)
```

Antman's solution using the power of MACRO

```
julia> macro datatype(a,b)
           return :( datatype($a - $b , $a * $b) )
       end
@datatype (macro with 1 method)

julia> f = @datatype( 105 , 5 )
datatype(100, 525)
```